# Почему вместе с фоновыми фотографиями затемняется и текст?

Tags: html, css

[image: Как сделать чтобы текст не затемнялся?]

```css
.slider__div {
  display: flex;
  height: 660px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.slider__section {
  width: 33%;
  height: 460px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background-size: cover;
  /*justify-content: space-between;*/
  margin-left: 0;
}

.slider__section::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.slider__ {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.slider__title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.slider__text {
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<section class="slider">
          <div class="slider__div">
            <div
              class="slider__section"
              style="background-image: url(Images/1вариант.jpg)"
            >
              <div class="container">
                <div class="slider__">
                  <h2 class="slider__title">ДИЗАЙН И СТРОИТЕЛЬСТВО</h2>
                  <p class="slider__text">
                    Совокупность зданий и сооружений, создающих пространственную
                    среду для жизни и деятельности человека
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div
              class="slider__section"
              style="background-image: url(Images/2вариант.jpg)"
            >
              <div class="container">
                <div class="slider__">
                  <h2 class="slider__title">СТРОИТЕЛЬСТВО И РЕМОНТ</h2>
                  <p class="slider__text">
                    Процесс их изменения, восстановления, улучшения, доведения
                    до первоначальных характеристик
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div
              class="slider__section"
              style="background-image: url(Images/3вариант.jpg)"
            >
              <div class="container">
                <div class="slider__">
                  <h2 class="slider__title">ОТДЕЛКА ИНТЕРЬЕРОВ</h2>
                  <p class="slider__text">
                    Оформление поверхностей стен, установку напольного покрытия,
                    украшение помещения мебельным гарнитуром
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Потому что через `position: absolute;` вы поместили этот фон над текстом

Comment: И как посоветуете лучше сделать, исправил на relative Получилось что не только текст а целая строка стала светлой

Comment: @ДанилВишняков, зачем создавать новый профиль, если в [старом профиле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/582705/danil-vishnyakov) есть непринятые ответы, решения из которых Вы успешно используете?

Comment: @ДанилВишняков добавьте псевдоклассу отрицательный `z-index` и проблема исчезнет.

Comment: @UModeL От старого профиля проблемы со входом на почту, поэтому создал новый